# How to move cell values around in dataframe

Tags: r

let's say I have the following data frame, and need to move the cell value "5900" over to where "test" is currently. How would I proceed?

| No. of CITES tag | No. of Alligators | No. of Females |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | Another Number | row |
| 50 | 590 | 5900 |

Comment: What is your expected output? Move 5900 to test and test to 5900? What is the general criteria for the movements?

Comment: Eliminate test completely by copying 5900 over it. I don't know that I understand general critera for movements.

Comment: I mean what is the pattern as to why replacements are done? Moving a single value is simple but when you have multiple values, there should be some pattern/reason. Why move 5900 for example instead of 590? Here we could hard code test with 5900 but having a more general idea why 5900 is chosen is useful for a more general solution.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. This is a class project where I am cleaning up an INCREDIBLY messy dataset that I got r to read and extract from a PDF with tables and all sorts of madness, so there isn't patterning on the dataframe, but there will be between documents, so I will be able to run the same code for all the pdfs and swap out the same cell values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace it by index. So, we take the 2nd value in the `No. of Females` column (i.e., `5900`), and replace the first value in the `No. of CITES tag` column with 5900.

```
df$`No. of CITES tag`[1] <- df$`No. of Females`[2]
```

You can also do it by row and column index.

```
df[1,1] <- df[2,3]
```

**Output**

```
  No. of CITES tag No. of Alligators No. of Females
1             5900    Another Number            row
2               50               590           5900
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(`No. of CITES tag` = c("5900", "50"), `No. of Alligators` = c("Another Number", 
"590"), `No. of Females` = c("row", "5900")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The power and speed of the internet is amazing--THANK YOU!